# How do you see what environment variables for services such as RDS are defined in elastic beanstalk?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, amazon-rds

When you create a RDS backed elastic beanstalk application it will show you some of the connection details on the Configuration > Data Tier > RDS page, and says that, "You can access connectivity information for this RDS DB Instance through environment variables." However, it doesn't show you what environment variables it defines (such as RDS_DB, RDS_DATABASE, or RDS_DB_NAME).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following variables will be auto defined:

```
RDS_DB_NAME
RDS_HOSTNAME
RDS_PORT
RDS_USERNAME
RDS_PASSWORD
```

However, I wouldn't suggest using the auto created RDS (unless it's for testing). Elastic Beantalk tends to take the db up/down as it see fit, so it's better to setup RDS yourself and define the above variables manually. [See more here](http://www.michaelgallego.fr/blog/2013/10/26/do-not-associate-rds-instance-with-beanstalk-environment/).